# How to run flutter test in Docker against local dev environment?

Tags: docker, flutter, dart-pub

One issue we've found with Flutter's screenshot (golden) tests is that they can be sensitive to differences on different platforms - a test that passes on one developer's Linux machine may fail on another's Macbook, for example. To mitigate these differences, we want to be able to run golden tests within a Docker container, so that tests can be perfectly reproducible across dev machines and CI.

If I clone our Flutter app repository fresh, and run:

`docker run -it --rm -v /path-to-repo:/code cirrusci/flutter:v1.12.13-hotfix.8 bash`

I can then run `flutter test` etc happily inside the container. Perfect!

However, there's a snag if I try and do the same thing, but this time with a repository which I've been working in locally.

First of all, I get a warning inside the container:

```
Warning! This package referenced a Flutter repository via the .packages file that is no longer available. The repository from which the 'flutter' tool is currently executing will be used instead.
  running Flutter tool: /home/cirrus/sdks/flutter
  previous reference  : /my-install-of-flutter/flutter
```

Then a whole slew of compiler errors along the lines of:

```
Compiler message:
/tmp/flutter_test_listener.JONVES/listener.dart:6:8: Error: Error when reading '/my-install-of-flutter/lib/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/flutter_test.dart': No such file or directory
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
```

I presume this is because `.packages` gets read by Flutter, but it's not applicable inside the container (as this has a totally different Flutter installation). Is there a way to get Flutter to ignore `.packages` so I can run these tests correctly inside a container?